# Prevent Rerendering in React in Dispatching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

How do I prevent rerendering using dispatching in React and Redux?
Currently, I have a card that can be toggle to open or not and I'm using redux dispatch.
My problem is that it becomes very slow when I have multiples items.

```
  const handleProductCard = useCallback((index) => {
    dispatch(toggleProductCard(index))
  }, [dispatch])


{
  products?.map((product, productIndex) => (
    <Grid key={product?.productCode || productIndex}>
      <Grid component="div" item xl={10} lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
        <ProductCard
          productIndex={productIndex}
          product={product}
          handleProductCard={handleProductCard}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  ));
}
```

Comment: When you toggle an item, your store should be updated or it just opens some kind of modal with data coming from the product?

Comment: @yousoumar. it expands/close this card using the productIndex. the store is updated